# How the pvalue is calculated in glm

Tags: r, glm

I'm using the `glm()` function in R, but for some reason I don't not understand how the p-values are calculated. What is the meaning of `Pr(>|z|)` here?

I read somewhere that the `p-values` are calculated as  `2*pnorm(z)`.  Considering this formula, my calculations does not result in what the `glm()` function is producing.

```
Call:  glm(formula = fmla, family = binomial(), data = tmpData, na.action = na.exclude)


Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)     -1.122521   0.286475  -3.918 8.91e-05 ***
var1             0.031535   0.001295  24.358  < 2e-16 ***
var2             0.247231   0.013977  17.688  < 2e-16 ***
var3            -0.952158   0.038288 -24.868  < 2e-16 ***


> 2*pnorm(c(-3.918, 24.35,17.68, -24.86))
[1]  8.928671e-05  2.000000e+00  2.000000e+00 2.015988e-136
```

Why do the p-values not correspond to the `glm()` output?

**Edit**: Running the fit through `summary()` gives me a more detailed result.

```
> summary(modelTmp)$coeff
                   Estimate  Std. Error    z value      Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)     -1.12252141 0.286475349  -3.918387  8.914334e-05
var1              0.03153534 0.001294648  24.358236 4.742122e-131
var2             0.24723122 0.013977256  17.688109  5.178450e-70
var3            -0.95215794 0.038288424 -24.868037 1.650303e-136



> 2*pnorm(c(-3.918387,-24.868037))
[1]  8.914350e-05 1.650297e-136
> 2*pnorm(c(24.3582,17.688))
[1] 2 2
```

Comment: Look at the source of `printCoefmat`.

Comment: Pr(>|z|) here means Pr(computed z (or z value)>absolute value of tabulated z)

Comment: For negative z-values, the p-values are ok, but for the positive ones, I am getting 2 which in no way even closer to  2e-16

Answer (score 2):

It's calculated as `2 * (1-pnorm(abs(-3.918)))`, which is twice (two-sided test) the depicted area under the normal distribution. (Actually, it's `2 * pnorm(-abs(-3.918))` in `summary.glm`, which is theoretically the same but numerically more precise.)

[image]

The statistics differ if `!family %in%  c("poisson","binomial") | !is.null(dispersion)`.

Comment: The family is binomial, for intercept and var3, the `2*pnorm(z)` calculation is exact. the problem is with the `var1` and `var2` calculation.

Comment: @learner - The full z value isn't printed so if you just used the printed z value to get your p-value it will be *slightly* different than the reported one.  You're basically just being REALLY picky if you're calling 1.650303e-136 different from 1.650297e-136

Comment: @Dason thanks, Actually I am concerned about the p-values of `var1` and `var2`. I just wanted to say that using `2*pnorm(c(-3.918387,-24.868037))` match the glm result while `2*pnorm(c(24.3582,17.688))` giving me a value of 2 which is in now way close to what i get from glm

Comment: @learner Oh well Roland already explained that.  And p-value calculations literally are probability calculations so you should realize that something is wrong with those p-values since they aren't between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Roland, Can you please explain your last statement in simple terms. "the statistics differs..."

Comment: @learner If family is poisson or binomial or is there is a value specified for dispersion then the test statistic is assumed to follow a standard normal distribution.  If not then a t distribution is assumed for the test statistic.

Comment: @Dawson, In my case, its the family is binomial and will follow standard normal distribution. Thus the formula `2 * (1-pnorm(abs(z)))` applies. However, if you calculate the pvalues from the `z` in my example above (in OP), it only pvalue of intercept matches, other do not.

Comment: @learner The simple z-statistics only applies for the binomial and poisson families without dispersion. `2 * (1-pnorm(abs(z)))` is not as precise numerically for very small probabilities as `2 * pnorm(-abs(-3.918))`. That's why `summary.glm` uses the latter. Calculating on the log-scale, i.e. `log(2)+pnorm(-abs(c(-3.918, 24.35,17.68, -24.86)), log.p = TRUE)`, might be even more precise for extremely small p-values.

Answer (score 0):

First, as @Roland pointed out, it's not `2 * pnorm(z)`. It's `2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(z))`. This gives the area under both the upper and lower tails of the normal distribution that is a distance of `z` or more from the origin. That's the textbook definition for a two-tailed P-value. The two expressions happen to be equal for `z` negative, but not so for `z` positive (as you discovered).

Second, your Z-statistics for var1 and var2 are large enough that they require special treatment. By default, `pnorm` calculates the area under the *lower* tail; that is, the probability `Pr(Z < z)`. If z is sufficiently large, this probability becomes numerically indistinguishable from 1; hence, taking `1 - Pr(Z < z)` will return 0. For situations like this, set the `lower.tail` argument to `FALSE`; this makes `pnorm` return the area under the *upper* tail, ie `Pr(Z > z)`.

```
> 2*pnorm(24.3582, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 4.746252e-131

> 2*(1 - pnorm(24.3582))
[1] 0
```

Comment: Or `2 * pnorm(-24.3582)` as implemented in `summary.glm`. However, if you need to distinguish 4.7e-131 from 0, I would first ask why you need that.